# Generate XML from Java annotations in Maven

Tags: xml, maven, annotations, maven-3

I need to generate XML files from custom Java annotations as a part of Maven build process. These XMLs are to be inclueded in the output jar. What's the cleanest way of doing it? I'm on Maven 3 and Java 7.

Background is that I need one XML file per each annotated class that contains description of the class. This is to access the description runtime without the need to load the class (I'm in an OSGi container so loading a class might trigger a bundle start).

Cheers, 
Pawel

Answer (score -2):

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/public-book.html
This helped me well enough, generating XML files is also provided

Comment: Can you point to the place where generating XML is described?

Comment: We ask that answers not simply provide a link, because the link might stop working some day. Could you edit your answer to include a summary of the relevant information from the linked reference?